# How to create stream in buffer rathen then in file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have code to convert audiofile I get from client to "wav" with required parameters using sox.

```
var sox = require('sox-stream');
...
var transcode = sox({
    output: {
        bits: 16,
        rate: 8000,
        channels: 1,
        type: 'wav'
    }
})
...
app.post('/m', function (req, res, next) {
  var mediaBuffer = req.files.media.data;
  arrayBufferToAudioBuffer(mediaBuffer)
    .then(audioBuffer => {
      var wav = toWav(audioBuffer);
      var chunk = new Uint8Array(wav);
      var stream = bufferToStream(chunk);
      var outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('audio5.wav');
      stream.pipe(transcode).pipe(outputStream);
      res(I want to send buffer of getting file);
    })
});
```

This code works and it create file in my storage, but I don't want to create file, I want that stream writes to arrayBuffer and then sends this arrayBufffer in response. How can I create stream to arrayBuffer rather than in file?

Comment: `res` is a stream, you can pipe directly to it.

Comment: how, tell me please. And what will I get on client? arrayBuffer?

Comment: `.pipe(res)`...

Comment: i tried stream.pipe(transcode).pipe(res);, but get Error: write after end.

Comment: Where do you get that error? You wouldn’t have a `res.send` or something equivalent around?

Comment: no, I have just replaced .pipe(outputstream) to .pipe(res)

Comment: Try stream.pipe(res).

Comment: but I need to make transoce instart, after send

Comment: Please show the backtrace you get (the full error message), and include what the line numbers shown map to in your source.